# Symfony subdomain routing

Tags: dns, symfony, plesk

I have a problem with subdomain routing.

I want to have administration on subdomain **admin.domain.com**

```
admin:
    host:     "www.admin.domain.com"
    resource: "@WebAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    schemes:  [https]

shop:
    resource: "@WebShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    schemes:  [https]
```

but from **admin** I can access to routes in **shop**

My  DNS:

```
CNAME admin is an alias of domain.com
CNAME www.admin is an alias of admin.domain.com
```

Plesk configuration:

admin.domain.com has the same documentroot as domain.com

Can someone help me with it?

Comment: There is no requirement about host in shop section, so it is accessible for every host. Add host requirement to this section to limit access.

Comment: Oh.... Thanks, idk how I messed it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add a subdomains, you can do this in different ways. The most simple one is:

Define routes in routing.yml like you did this before, but there are a problem with www - don't use it. So, you your host directive for admin area will be `host:     "admin.domain.com"`

We have small changes in routing.yml

```
admin:
host:     "admin.domain.com"
resource: "@WebAdminBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
schemes:  [https]

shop:
resource: "@WebShopBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
schemes:  [https]
```

In the config.yml you can define the domain_name variable:

```
parameters:

    #... 

    domain_name: "domain.com"
```

It is not necessary, but it is very conveniently!

And in the security.yml access_control directives. First three paths - is an example to use with fosuser, the last one is for your admin area access via "admin" subdomain

```
security:

    # ...

    access_control:
    - { path: ^/login$,     host: ^%domain_name%$,            role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/register,   host: ^%domain_name%$,            role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - { path: ^/resetting,  host: ^%domain_name%$,            role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
    - {                     host: ^admin\.%domain_name%$,     roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

It is not the best practice, but this solution resolve the problem with subdomains